# calculating $\sin x$ in floating point arithmetic

Tags: numerical-methods, floating-point

I would like some help in the following exercise:
In floating point arithmetic we want to calculate $\sin 30$ using the type $$\sin x=\sum_{k=0}^{N}t_{k}$$ where $t_{0}=x,t_{k}=-t_{k-1}\frac{x^2}{(2k+2)(2k+3)}$.
For $N\ge 40$ the result remains the same $ -0.204857 \cdot 10^5$.
Now I am asked to explain this phenomenon.
I thought that this is happening because $t_{40},t_{41},...$ are too small in comparison to the sum till $k=39$, but how do I prove it in a formal way?

Comment: $30^\circ$ and $30$ radians are very different things. Which one?

Comment: just 30, not radians

Comment: So, $\pi/6$? What happens if you plug that into your expression?

Comment: Your recursive formula is wrong: you have $t_1=-x^3/20$ but it should be $-x^3/6$. Your denominator should be $(2k)(2k+1)$ instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong, the terms are not too small but to **large**. Actually you
compute the Taylor series of $\sin(x)$ for $x=30$. The largest term is for
$k=14$ and is about $7.762\times 10^{11}.$

To actually compute the sum with say double-precision floating point
arithmetic, all your **large** terms must cancel to give a value $\approx
-0.99.$

This is almost impossible because your terms are not computed exactly
and there will be truncation errors of order at least $10^{12}$ machine
epsilons.

Comment: There are two different things occurring: 1. the earlier terms are too large and of opposite sign, so you have catastrophic cancellation; 2. the later terms are too small to have any numerical impact on the earlier terms. The second one explains why the answer doesn't change when you ramp up $N$ past a certain point. The first one explains part of why the answer is so horribly wrong. (The other major part is that the formula for the summands is wrong.)